# Yahoo BOSS API Python Library Error

Tags: python, yahoo-boss-api

i've just downloaded the Yahoo BOSS Mashup framework from http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/mashup.html, and I have a problem:

I'm receiving the following error for all examples. For instance, for example.ex3.py:

```
File "ex3.py", line 33
    tb = db.group(by=["ynews$title"], key="dg$diggs", reducer=lambda d1, d2: d1 + d2, as: 'rank', table=tb, norm=text.norm)
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I read the post at [Python 2.6 DB error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774752/python-2-6-db-error) 
but i do not understand the solution.

How do i fix the problem?

Is there any other alternate libraries i can use?

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, i manage to fix it. What i did is that i changed the key word "as" and replace it with some other word.

I used "as" to "as1" and reinstalled the framework. Now it works. Hope this helps all other people.